# Splitting string into rows with common pattern (DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where a specific column has been filled with data, which is effectively concatenating as it grows, per job number. Not my database design as this is creating a lot of varchar(max) fields, sometimes with less than 250 characters, buts its what ive got to work with.

**I am trying to create a view that can seperate these lines that have been added, into separate rows.** and there is one common string. When a new line is added it always starts with this format: `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:` for example:

> 05/10/2017 11:25: Joe Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however
>   additional parts were required 06/10/2017 08:15: Billy Earner attended
>   site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.

**Is this possible?** I have split strings before with a symbol, such as a semi-colon, but this is a lot more complex

Comment: Cross apply on a CLR Table valued function that splits the string on a regex.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."* - you have to show some code as an attempt

Comment: I can add some code for the splitting of strings, but I didn't feel it applies as it may be irrelivent when the regex is added. And there is no shame in asking questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple different ways to go about it... The 1st uses a tally function (same basic principal as a tally table). The other uses a recursive cte. Under normal circumstances, a tally type splitter will be the fastest sql based approach available but it does start to suffer as the number of characters between splits increases.

Either way, you can test them both and see which works better in your application.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    BigString VARCHAR(MAX)
    );
INSERT #TestData (BigString) VALUES
    ('05/10/2017 11:25: Joe A.X attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 06/10/2017 01:15: Billy X attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('06/10/2017 11:25: Joe B Bloggs X site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 06/10/2017 02:15: Billy Earner X site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('07/10/2017 11:25: Joe C Bloggs attended X to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 06/10/2017 03:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  05/10/2017 03:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('08/10/2017 11:25: Joe D Bloggs attended site to X a problem, however additional parts were required. 06/10/2017 04:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  05/10/2017 04:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('09/10/2017 11:25: Joe E Bloggs attended site to fix a X, however additional parts were X. 06/10/2017 06:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, X the new on  05/10/2017 06:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('01/10/2017 11:25: Joe F Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 06/10/2017 07:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  05/10/2017 07:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('02/10/2017 11:25: Joe G Bloggs attended site X fix a problem, however X parts were required1 06/10/2017 08:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  05/10/2017 05/10/2017 08:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('03/10/2017 11:25: Joe H Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required! 06/10/2017 09:15: Billy Earner attended site, and X the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('04/10/2017 11:25: Joe I Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required? 06/10/2017 10:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('05/10/2017 11:25: Joe J Bloggs X site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required! 06/10/2017 11:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on. 05/10/2017 11:25: Joe J Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 06/10/2017 11:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('06/10/2017 11:25: Joe K Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 06/10/2017 12:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on. 06/10/2017 11:25: Joe K Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 06/10/2017 12:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('07/10/2017 11:25: Joe L Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 06/10/2017 13:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on. 07/10/2017 11:25: Joe L Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 06/10/2017 13:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.'),
    ('08/10/2017 11:25: Joe M Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional X were X. 06/10/2017 14:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the X item, with the new on.');

--=============================================================================================================
```

The tally version...

```
-- option 1... tally table or tally function ...
SELECT 
    td.Id,
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
    Item = SUBSTRING(td.BigString, t.n, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %', STUFF(td.BigString, 1, t.n, '')), 0), LEN(td.BigString)))
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY dbo.tfn_Tally(LEN(td.BigString), 1) t
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(td.BigString, t.n, 18)) ) pd (PatDelim)
WHERE
    pd.PatDelim LIKE '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: ';
```

And recursion...

```
-- option 2... recursion
WITH
    cte_Recursive AS (
        SELECT 
            td.Id, 
            ItemNumber = 1,
            i.Item,
            Remainder = STUFF(td.BigString, 1, LEN(i.Item), '')
        FROM
            #TestData td
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(td.BigString, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %',STUFF(td.BigString, 1, 21, '')), 0), LEN(td.BigString)) + 19))) i (Item)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            r.Id,
            ItemNumber = r.ItemNumber + 1,
            i.Item,
            Remainder = STUFF(r.Remainder, 1, LEN(i.Item), '')
        FROM
            cte_Recursive r
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(r.Remainder, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %',
                                                                                                                                                             stuff(LTRIM(r.Remainder), 1, 1, '')
                                                                                                                                                                            ), 0), LEN(r.Remainder) + 18))) ) i (Item)
        WHERE 
            PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]: %', r.Remainder) > 0
            --LEN(r.Remainder) > 0
        )
SELECT 
    r.Id, 
    r.ItemNumber, 
    r.Item
FROM
    cte_Recursive r
ORDER BY
    r.Id,
    r.ItemNumber;
```

The results based on the test data...

```
Id          ItemNumber           Item
----------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           1                    05/10/2017 11:25: Joe A.X attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 
1           2                    06/10/2017 01:15: Billy X attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
2           3                    06/10/2017 11:25: Joe B Bloggs X site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 
2           4                    06/10/2017 02:15: Billy Earner X site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
3           5                    07/10/2017 11:25: Joe C Bloggs attended X to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 
3           6                    06/10/2017 03:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  
3           7                    05/10/2017 03:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
4           8                    08/10/2017 11:25: Joe D Bloggs attended site to X a problem, however additional parts were required. 
4           9                    06/10/2017 04:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  
4           10                   05/10/2017 04:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
5           11                   09/10/2017 11:25: Joe E Bloggs attended site to fix a X, however additional parts were X. 
5           12                   06/10/2017 06:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, X the new on  
5           13                   05/10/2017 06:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
6           14                   01/10/2017 11:25: Joe F Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 
6           15                   06/10/2017 07:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  
6           16                   05/10/2017 07:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
7           17                   02/10/2017 11:25: Joe G Bloggs attended site X fix a problem, however X parts were required1 
7           18                   06/10/2017 08:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on  05/10/2017 
7           19                   05/10/2017 08:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
8           20                   03/10/2017 11:25: Joe H Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required! 
8           21                   06/10/2017 09:15: Billy Earner attended site, and X the faulty item, with the new on.
9           22                   04/10/2017 11:25: Joe I Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required? 
9           23                   06/10/2017 10:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
10          24                   05/10/2017 11:25: Joe J Bloggs X site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required! 
10          25                   06/10/2017 11:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on. 
10          26                   05/10/2017 11:25: Joe J Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 
10          27                   06/10/2017 11:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
11          28                   06/10/2017 11:25: Joe K Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 
11          29                   06/10/2017 12:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on. 
11          30                   06/10/2017 11:25: Joe K Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 
11          31                   06/10/2017 12:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
12          32                   07/10/2017 11:25: Joe L Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required. 
12          33                   06/10/2017 13:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on. 
12          34                   07/10/2017 11:25: Joe L Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional parts were required 
12          35                   06/10/2017 13:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the faulty item, with the new on.
13          36                   08/10/2017 11:25: Joe M Bloggs attended site to fix a problem, however additional X were X. 
13          37                   06/10/2017 14:15: Billy Earner attended site, and replaced the X item, with the new on.
```

Here is the code for the tfn_Tally function...

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_Tally
/* ============================================================================
07/20/2017 JL, Created. Capable of creating a sequense of rows 
                ranging from -10,000,000,000,000,000 to 10,000,000,000,000,000
============================================================================ */
(
    @NumOfRows BIGINT,
    @StartWith BIGINT 
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
RETURN
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10 rows
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100 rows
        cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),                             -- 10,000 rows
        cte_n4 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b),                             -- 100,000,000 rows
        cte_Tally (n) AS (
            SELECT TOP (@NumOfRows)
                (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) + @StartWith
            FROM 
                cte_n4 a CROSS JOIN cte_n4 b                                                    -- 10,000,000,000,000,000 rows
            )
    SELECT 
        t.n
    FROM 
        cte_Tally t;

GO
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, very well explained, I have applied your recursion answer to my scenario and has worked brilliantly!

Comment: That's great, I'm glad you were able to use one of them. Also, I appreciate the good feedback. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the strings are *accumulating* on different rows.  (Perhaps this is a misunderstanding.)

If so you can do this without much fussy string processing.  The idea is to use the previous value to construct the string:

```
select t.*,
       (case when prev_col is null then col
             else stuff(col, 1, len(prev_col), '')
        end)
from (select t.*,
             lag(col) over (partition by left(col, 17) order by col) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/PKEL77588) of this method.